# Granting access with RFID card

Tags: c, arduino

I've got a problem with my arduino program. I'm using a RFID reader to scan cards (this part works flawlessly). I want the program to grant access to using some buttons (doesn't matter to be honest). The user who uses a verified card can use the functionalities until he scans a card again. I've deleted some unnecessary parts of the code.

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <MFRC522.h>

String read_rfid;
String ok_rfid_1="a3f90f7"; //ID of the verified CARD
const int buzzer=8; //Buzzer
const int redLed=7; 
const int greenLed=6; 
const int yellowLed=5;
byte access=false;       // 

void setup() {
Serial.begin(9600);         // Initialize serial communications with the PC
SPI.begin();                // Init SPI bus
mfrc522.PCD_Init();         // Init MFRC522 card
}

/*
* Helper routine to dump a byte array as hex values to Serial.
 */
void dump_byte_array(byte *buffer, byte bufferSize) {
read_rfid="";
for (byte i = 0; i < bufferSize; i++) {
    read_rfid=read_rfid + String(buffer[i], HEX);
}
}

void granted() {    }  //it lights up the green led

void denied() {    } //it lights up the red led

void login() {
if (read_rfid==ok_rfid_1) {
  granted();
  access=true;
  } else { 
  denied();
  }
 delay(1000);
}

void logout() {
if (read_rfid==ok_rfid_1 && access==1) {
  access=false;
  Serial.println("Logout ");
  }
}

void loop() {
// Look for new cards
if ( ! mfrc522.PICC_IsNewCardPresent())
    return;

// Select one of the cards
if ( ! mfrc522.PICC_ReadCardSerial())
    return;

dump_byte_array(mfrc522.uid.uidByte, mfrc522.uid.size);
Serial.println(read_rfid);
login();
   while(access==true)
     {logout();};

}
```

The logging in part works well, but it logs out automatically. As I observed the problem might be that `if(read_rfid==ok_rfid_1 && access==1)` is always true, because the `read_rfid` does not change. Do you have any ideas to solve my dillema?

Comment: `access` is already a boolean, change `access==1` to just `access` and `while(access == true) -> while(access)`.

Comment: You have `while(access==true)     {logout();};` here, but there doesn't seem to be any code that reads new data anywhere that could change `ok_rfid_1` or `access`